# VueJS set data in methods function

Tags: vue.js

This is my code, HTML:

```
<div id="myApp">
   <div class="items">
      <div class="item" v-for="quiz in quizzes" :key="quiz.id"}
         <span>{{ quiz.question }}</span>
         <span v-if="selected[quiz.key]">{{ quiz.answer }}</span>
         <a href: "#" v-on:click="quizSelect(quiz.key, $event)">Select</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
new Vue({
   el: '#myApp'
   data: {
      selected: {},
      quizzes: [
         {
            key: 'k1',
            question: 'This is question 1',
            answer: 'This is answer 1'
         },
         {
            key: 'k2',
            question: 'This is question 2',
            answer: 'This is answer 2'
         }
      ]
   },
   methods: {
      quizSelect: function(key, e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         this.selected[key] = 'selected';
      }
   }
})
```

I want when click to "Selecct", quiz anwser will show. But when i click "Select", nothing happend. What's wrong? Somebody can help me???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the line:

```
this.selected[key] = 'selected';
```

to:

```
this.$set(this.selected, key, 'selected');
```

See [vue reactivity in depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).

```js
new Vue({
   el: '#myApp',
   data: {
      selected: {},
      quizzes: [
         {
            key: 'k1',
            question: 'This is question 1',
            answer: 'This is answer 1'
         },
         {
            key: 'k2',
            question: 'This is question 2',
            answer: 'This is answer 2'
         }
      ]
   },
   methods: {
      quizSelect: function(key, e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         this.$set(this.selected, key, 'selected');
         // this.selected[key] = 'selected';
      }
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="myApp">
   <div class="items">
      <div class="item" v-for="quiz in quizzes" :key="quiz.id">
         <span>{{ quiz.question }}</span>
         <span v-if="selected[quiz.key]">{{ quiz.answer }}</span>
         <a href="#" v-on:click="quizSelect(quiz.key, $event)">Select</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```